# Android Kotlin - Volley Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, kotlin-android-extensions

I made REST API using Django and now I want to connect it to android. I'm using Kotlin and Volley library. I created code and I'm still getting this error:

> E/Volley: [287] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/login/.

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
        val jsonObj = JSONObject()

        val LOGIN_API_URL = "http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/login/"

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            jsonObj.put("username", username.text)
            jsonObj.put("password", passwd.text)

            val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
            val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_API_URL,
                    Response.Listener {
                        response ->
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener {
                        error ->
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    })

            que.add(req)

        }
```

I saw that problem might by with `Content-Type`, so I tried with this line, I added it under `jsonObj.put("password", passwd.text)`.

Here is this line:
`jsonObj.put("Content-Type", "application/json")`.

And here is some test login data:

> username: testUser1232
>
> password: test123123

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: are you try add Content-Type to the headers?

Comment: are you sending the token

Comment: @vikaskumar I'm not using any tokens in my API

Comment: 400 is means we are making bad api requests so there is something missing or we are not sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the [JsonObjectRequest](http://griosf.github.io/android-volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html#JsonObjectRequest-int-java.lang.String-org.json.JSONObject-com.android.volley.Response.Listener-com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener-) you don't pass the `jsonObj` to it.

Try:

```
val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_API_URL, jsonObj,
                    Response.Listener {
                        response ->
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener {
                        error ->
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    })
```

Comment: So how can I put username and password ?

Comment: Check my answer. Just edited it with an example. See if it works out and if you understand it.